# deploy django to elastic beanstalk gert degraded

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image: Image error]

This is the firs time i trying work deploy python dijango with elasticbeanstalk , it show me successfull but it get degraded and show me this error

Connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

now how to config it to reslove this promblem

now how to config it to reslove this promblem